# How to support PHP variables with exec command?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

Hello I am sending mail from php. I am fetching to address and cc address from database and storing them in one one variable.
$to,$cc i need to use this in mailx command.
Following query is hardcoded and its working.

```
 exec('echo "hey i am there" | mailx -S smtp=10.0.8.8:25 -r support@gmail.com -s "Alert" pratik@gmail.com');
```

Need to replace

```
 $message = hey i am there
 $to=pratik@gmail.com
 $from =support@gmail.com 
 $subject = Alert

exec('echo $message | mailx -S smtp=10.0.8.8:25 -r $from  -s $subject $to');
```

But the above thing is not working

Comment: Just change `'` to `"` like `exec("echo $message | mailx -S smtp=10.0.8.8:25 -r $from  -s $subject $to");`

Comment: use double quote instead of single quote

Comment: There's two good answers now, please accept one of them so other people can benefit from them!

Comment: @Loek i am getting error as below  smtp-server: 501 5.1.3 Invalid address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change `'` to `"` like

```
exec("echo $message | mailx -S smtp=10.0.8.8:25 -r $from  -s $subject $to");
```

Comment: I'd recommend adding some calls to `escapeshellarg` as well

Answer (score 2):

You should concatenate your strings.

`exec('echo ' . $message . ' | mailx -S smtp=10.0.8.8:25 -r ' . $from . ' -s  ' . $subject . ' ' . $to);`

Comment: You missed the `$message`